# How to check if HTTP request is originating from AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I use AWS API Gateway that proxies HTTP queries to my services. How could my services check that HTTP requests are originating from AWS API Gateway?

Comment: Client certificates are the only way to do backend authentication right now, as @jen walter has suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use client-side certificates to authenticate requests between API-Gateway and your server.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

> You can use API Gateway to generate an SSL certificate and use its public key in the backend to verify that HTTP requests to your backend system are from API Gateway. This allows your HTTP backend to control and accept only requests originating from Amazon API Gateway, even if the backend is publicly accessible.
>
> The SSL certificates that are generated by API Gateway are self-signed and only the public key of a certificate is visible in the API Gateway console or through the APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Since Nov 30, 2017 [Amazon API Gateway Supports Endpoint Integrations with Private VPCs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-api-gateway-supports-endpoint-integrations-with-private-vpcs/).

You create an endpoint to your VPC by setting up a VPC link between your VPC and a Network Load Balancer (NLB), which is provided by Elastic Load Balancing. The NLB send requests to multiple destinations in your VPC such as Amazon EC2 instances, Auto Scaling groups, or Amazon ECS services.

[How to Set up API Gateway Private Integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html)